# android ndk and eclipse give different error info about a c++ getline() function

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, c++11, android-ndk

i have some c++ code under android JNI, when i using the ndk-build under command line , it can generated .so libfile, but when run my project as android application, the eclipse alert some error about the getline() function, it tell me must first fix error first. so i am confused.

my getline() function is used here:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_android_mymapsforge_create(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    ifstream infile("C:\\Users\\li\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\importANN\\Debug\\nodes.csv");
    string line;
    int index = 0;

   while( getline( infile, line ))
   {
         ...
   }
}
```

the given getline() info is :
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
std::basic_istream<#0,#1> & getline(std::basic_istream<#0,#1> &, std::basic_string<#0,#1,#2> &)
std::basic_istream<#0,#1> & getline(std::basic_istream<#0,#1> &, std::basic_string<#0,#1,#2> &, #0)

but in fact, the android-ndk has build sucessfully the c++ code:
see the console info:

```
Build of configuration Default for project MyMapsforge
C:\TDDOWNLOAD\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\ndk\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Install        : libann.so => libs/armeabi/libann.so
Install        : libann.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libann.so

**** Build Finished ****
```

y pasted  this function is containde in my android.mk c++ file

see my android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ 

LOCAL_MODULE    := libann
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ANN.cpp \
    bd_pr_search.cpp \
    bd_tree.cpp \
    kd_pr_search.cpp \
    kd_split.cpp \
    kd_util.cpp \
    bd_fix_rad_search.cpp \
    bd_search.cpp \
    brute.cpp \
    kd_fix_rad_search.cpp \
    kd_search.cpp \
    kd_tree.cpp \
    kd_dump.cpp \
    perf.cpp\
    sample.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

the sample.cpp is which contained my pasted function have used the getline() function. So i am confused, how to solved the problem.

Eclipse remind it contains error so i can not run the project.

Comment: Normally I'd say that the actual ndk-gcc, and not Eclipse, is what you really need to satisfy (you can simply turn Eclipse checking off if you don't feel like pointing it at the supporting files). However your attempt to reference a file on the development machine by a windows path, in what your tags suggest is android-ndk code, is extremely mistaken - that file won't be accessible as the program will not be running on the windows box, but rather on a real or emulated android device with no access to C:. So it's not the error messages, but the whole idea, which should be of concern right now.

Comment: i got your meaning. you advise me to turn the eclispe checking code off.  Another thing is that your notice that my code is mistaken, i know it, i am not correcting it already, i will pass the file path in the export function as jstring object, and then do somthing. thanks for your advise.

Comment: @Chris-Stratton: except that the Application.mk is tuned to **clang** and not **gcc**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get stuck with these error messages from Eclipse, you should simply go to the "Problems" view and delete the messages. Clean build the project, and the messages will not appear again. Note that by the [book](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/APPLICATION-MK.html), `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` should be specified in **Application.mk**. Also note, that you must specify `APP_STL` for your project, and this setting also goes into **Application.mk**.

See the NDK [CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html) for explanations. But, to make the long story short, you have the follwing choices (with NDK r9b):

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_STL := stlport_shared
APP_STL := libc++_static
APP_STL := libc++_shared
```

The following choices do not include `std::ifstream`:

```
APP_STL := gabi++_static
APP_STL := gabi++_shared
APP_STL := system
```

Note that **libc++_** were not available before NDK r9, and are not documented well as of today.